# Adding HTML just to a block

Tags: blocks

I've added a node as a block to my home page (using nodesinblock module). I've got it looking basically like I want it to look with the teaser appearing in the block, but I'd like to add a 'read more' link (or button) to the bottom of the block.

Note: I do NOT want this 'read more' link to appear on the full content node, just the block.

Anyone know how to add some html specifically to a block on the home page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this module today when I saw your post, if you don't want the 'read more' to appear on a full content node display you could create a new display template and add the php path/read more html link on the template you created then choose it from the render mode of node in block settings.

But I'm a little curious, why did you not use views block instead? it's a lot easier, you could just put the read more link on the footer.

Comment: thanks for the tips. I don't know how to create a view block that ONLY displays one specific node. suggestions?

Comment: nvm I figured out how to show a specific node in a block; super easy. Just add the filter to be the specific node :p